# Asp.Net sending outlook email and get this 5.7.57 SMTP Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, outlook

I am sending outlook email with asp.net c#.

When I run this, I got an error at (smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);) I search online and try to solve at came up with nothing. Please send help. I really appreciate it.

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string eml = "xxx@mymail.com";
        var fromAddress = "xxx@outlook.com";
        var toAddress = eml;
        const string fromPassword = "password";
        string subject = "Subject testing";
        string body = "Welcome..";
        // smtp settings
        var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com");
        {
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials =
                new System.Net.NetworkCredential(fromPassword, fromPassword);
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Credentials = credentials;
        }
        // Passing values to smtp object
        smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

At the line:

```
new System.Net.NetworkCredential(fromPassword, fromPassword)
```

You have fromPassword for both parameters instead of having the username and the password

```
new System.Net.NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword)
```

Comment: Oh, it is because they have the same values. It is a must to put the value for both parameters?